# Flat texture and transparency

Tags: shaders, transparency

[image]

Hello, how may I make the black parts transparent but keep the texture flat at the same time ?
[image]
On the second picture,I used Principal BSDF it makes the black parts transparent but the texture looses it's flatness.

How may I do it please

Comment: What do you mean with "loses it's flatness"? Maybe you wanna try _Alpha Clip_ with some _Clip Threshold_ in the material's _Blend Mode_ options?

Comment: I meant that when I used principled BSDF the hair didn't looked flat anymore,  but Markus von Broady gave me a solution. Thank you so much though 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect color to output, the *Emission* shader is used implicitly. So to reproduce the same effect with transparency, use the *Emission* shader connected to a *Mix Shader* controlled by *Alpha*. The other shader to mix is the *Transparent* shader:

[image]

And as a fun fact, you could set the following settings in the Principled BSDF for the same effect (irrelevant settings hidden):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! That's the exact result I wanted 